# swagger2 for springboot microservice do no produce response on ui

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, swagger-ui

I created one micro service with spring boot, I don't have resource folder and i wanted to add swagger support. So I followed as per [document](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

So

1. Added swagger dependency.
2. Added docker class as it is
3. Added swagger's ui dependency

Results

1. http://localhost:port/myservice/v2/api-docs ->
    Response is as per expectation.
2. http://localhost:port/myservice/v2/api-docs ->
    Response is as per expectation.
3. But 
   http://localhost:port/myservice/swagger-ui.html ->
   Not expected response, on browser console i am getting error

   GET http://localhost:port/myservice/configuration/ui 404 (Not Found)

As its microservice, I don't have `@EnableWebMvc` class.

What Am I missing ?

Comment: try "http://localhost:8338/swagger-ui.html"

Comment: I tried, but it results with 
This localhost page can’t be found
On browser's console as expected 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: please post your code snippets of Spring config, dependency config, sample response of v2/api-docs, etc.

Comment: It would be great if you shared your example on GitHub to make it more convenient for the community to help yourself.

Comment: Due to privacy agreement I can't publish the code, but i solved this issue by downgrading the version springfox-swagger-ui to 2.2.2 from 2.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Downgrading `springfox-swagger-ui` to 2.2.2 fixed my problem (as mentioned in the comments by [sailor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326844/swagger2-for-springboot-microservice-do-no-produce-response-on-ui#comment73889994_43326844).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am new and learning use of stack-overflow